# how to read a SAML encoded response and extract name ID

Tags: saml

I have posted the code here which I implemented.Iam initilaizing the SAML servlet when I click on a specific URL Ex:(https://wwwdev-lom.app.ford.com/launchomatic/launch/view.jsp?chronicleId=0900cad780aaac86&docbase=edmsdev) but when I click authenticate SAML the page redirects back to the ADFS page.The ADFS page is authenticated successfully.I would like the page to be redirected back to the same URL from which I clicked on.The link is supposed to help me download content from browser after authenticating ADFS .Should I build this URL again through JSP aand forward this servlet to JSP.If so how can I call from the current servlet(below one) to JSP and where do I call it in the below?

```
import com.documentum.com.DfClientX;
import com.ford.launchomatic.downloader.LaunchFile;
import com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfClient;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSession;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSessionManager;
import com.documentum.fc.common.IDfLoginInfo;
import com.documentum.wc.env.jsp.DwJSPPageContext;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap;
import org.opensaml.common.SAMLVersion;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Assertion;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.AuthnRequest;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.EncryptedAssertion;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Issuer;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Response;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.StatusMessage;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Subject;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.SubjectConfirmation;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.SubjectConfirmationData;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.AuthnRequestBuilder;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.IssuerBuilder;
import org.opensaml.xml.Configuration;
import org.opensaml.xml.XMLObject;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.Marshaller;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.Unmarshaller;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.UnmarshallerFactory;
import org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.Credential;
import org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509Credential;
import org.opensaml.xml.signature.Signature;
import org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator;
import org.opensaml.xml.util.Base64;
import org.opensaml.xml.util.XMLHelper;
import org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class AuthenticateSAML extends HttpServlet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  String path = null;
  static PrintWriter log;
  Properties prop;

  public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
    super.init(servletConfig);
    this.path = servletConfig.getServletContext().getRealPath(
        "/WEB-INF/classes/saml.properties");
  }



  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException { doPost(request, response); }



  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
      PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
      this.prop = new Properties();
      inputStream = new FileInputStream(this.path);
      this.prop.load(inputStream);
      inputStream.close();
      String logFile = this.prop.getProperty("logFile");
      createLog(logFile);
        Trace("==========START SAML SSO==========");
        Trace("Creating Authentication Request");
        String url = buildAuthenticationRequest(request,response);
        response.sendRedirect(url);
        String value = request.getParameter("SAMLResponse");
        if(validateResponse("xxxx",value))
            {
            Trace("SAML response validated successful");
            }
        String docbase = this.prop.getProperty("docbase");
        Boolean docbasesuccess = DFCAuthentication("xxxx", value, docbase);
        if(docbasesuccess)
        {
            Trace("docbase authentication successful");
        } 
        if (log != null) {
          log.flush();
          log.close();
        } 

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
      }
    } 
  }

  public String buildAuthenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
    String IDPurl = this.prop.getProperty("IDPurl");
    String ACSurl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String issuerURL = this.prop.getProperty("Issuer");

    IssuerBuilder issuerBuilder = new IssuerBuilder();
    Issuer issuer = issuerBuilder.buildObject("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", "Issuer", "saml");
    issuer.setValue(issuerURL);
    DateTime issueInstant = new DateTime();
    AuthnRequestBuilder authnRequestBuilder = new AuthnRequestBuilder();
    AuthnRequest authnRequest = authnRequestBuilder.buildObject();
    authnRequest.setForceAuthn(new Boolean(false));
    authnRequest.setIsPassive(new Boolean(false));
    authnRequest.setIssueInstant(issueInstant);
    authnRequest.setProtocolBinding("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
    authnRequest.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(ACSurl);
    authnRequest.setIssuer(issuer);
    authnRequest.setID("AQ1");
    authnRequest.setVersion(SAMLVersion.VERSION_20);
    Marshaller marshaller = Configuration.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller((XMLObject)authnRequest);
    Element authDOM = marshaller.marshall((XMLObject)authnRequest);
    authDOM.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "xml:space", "preserve");
    StringWriter rspWrt = new StringWriter();
    XMLHelper.writeNode(authDOM, rspWrt);
    String requestMessage = rspWrt.toString();
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater(8, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, deflater);
    deflaterOutputStream.write(requestMessage.getBytes());
    deflaterOutputStream.close();
    String encodedRequestMessage = Base64.encodeBytes(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), 8);
    String encodedAuthnRequest = URLEncoder.encode(encodedRequestMessage, "UTF-8");
    String url = String.valueOf(IDPurl) + "/?SAMLRequest=" + encodedAuthnRequest;
    return url;
  }

  static void Trace(String info) {
    if (log != null) {
      Date date = new Date();
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
          "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
      log.write(String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(date)) + " " + info);
      log.write(System.lineSeparator());
    } 
  }

  static void createLog(String fileName) {
    try {
      File logFile = new File(fileName);
      File logDir = new File(logFile.getParent());
      if (!logDir.exists())
        logDir.mkdir(); 
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
      log = new PrintWriter(fw);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }

  public static ArrayList<String> listFilesForFolder(File folder) {
    ArrayList<String> certList = new ArrayList<>();
    int flag = 0;
    if (folder == null || !folder.exists()) {
      Trace("Cannot load certificates. Folder doesn't exist: " + 
          folder.getAbsolutePath());
      return null;
    } 
    Trace("Retrieving Certificates in folder: " + folder.getAbsolutePath()); byte b; int i; File[] arrayOfFile;
    for (i = (arrayOfFile = folder.listFiles()).length, b = 0; b < i; ) { File fileEntry = arrayOfFile[b];
      if (!fileEntry.isDirectory()) {


        String path = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
        String name = fileEntry.getName();
        int extStart = name.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (extStart != -1) {
          String ext = name.substring(extStart + 1);
          if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("crt") || 
            ext.equalsIgnoreCase("cer") || 
            ext.equalsIgnoreCase("der")) {
            flag = 1;
            certList.add(path);
          } 
        } 
      }  b++; }

    if (flag == 0) {
      Trace("No certificates found...");
      return null;
    } 
    return certList;
  }


  public boolean isNullorEmpty(String value) { return !(value != null && value.trim() != ""); }



  public boolean validateResponse(String username, String responseMessage) throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
      if (this.prop == null)
        this.prop = new Properties(); 
      inputStream = new FileInputStream(this.path);
      this.prop.load(inputStream);
      inputStream.close();
      String certPath = this.prop.getProperty("certPath");
      Trace("User: " + username);
      if (isNullorEmpty(username) || isNullorEmpty(responseMessage)) {
        Trace("Username or SAMLToken cannot be null");
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 
      DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
      byte[] base64DecodedResponse = Base64.decode(responseMessage);
      ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
          base64DecodedResponse);
      DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
        .newDocumentBuilder();
      Document document = docBuilder.parse(is);
      Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
      UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = 
        Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory
        .getUnmarshaller(element);
      XMLObject responseXmlObj = unmarshaller.unmarshall(element);
      Response samlresponse = (Response)responseXmlObj;


      String statusCode = samlresponse.getStatus().getStatusCode()
        .getValue();
      Trace("Response status: " + statusCode);
      if (!statusCode.equals("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success")) {
        StatusMessage statusMessage = samlresponse.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
        Trace("Status code is not success");
        if (statusMessage != null) {
          String statusMessageText = null;
          statusMessageText = statusMessage.getMessage();
          Trace("Reason: " + statusMessageText);
        } 
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 


      Assertion assertion = null;
      Signature signature = null;
      List<Assertion> assertionList = samlresponse.getAssertions();
      if (assertionList.isEmpty()) {
        List<EncryptedAssertion> encassertionList = samlresponse
          .getEncryptedAssertions();
        if (encassertionList.isEmpty()) {
          Trace("Problem with retrieveing assertion/encrypted assertion from the provided SAML response");
          Trace("Authentication failure");
          return false;
        } 
        Trace("Encrypted Assertion is not supported right now. Please turn off encrypted assertion at the IdP");
        return false;
      } 

      assertion = assertionList.get(0);
      if (assertion == null) {
        Trace("The Response must contain at least one Assertion");
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 

      if (!assertion.isSigned() && !samlresponse.isSigned()) {
        Trace("Either assertion or response has to be signed ");
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 
      signature = assertion.getSignature();
      if (signature == null) {
        signature = samlresponse.getSignature();
        if (signature == null) {
          Trace("Problem  retrieving signature from the provided SAML response.");
          Trace("Authentication failure");
          return false;
        } 
      } 

      ArrayList<String> certList = listFilesForFolder(new File(certPath));
      if (certList == null) {
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 
      int success = 0;
      for (String name : certList) {
        Trace("Validating signature with certificate: " + name);
        File certificateFile = new File(name);

        SignatureValidator signatureValidator = null;
        X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = null;
        FileInputStream certInputStream = null;
        try {
          certInputStream = new FileInputStream(certificateFile);
          CertificateFactory certificateFactory = 
            CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
          X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory
            .generateCertificate(certInputStream);
          publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(certificate
              .getPublicKey().getEncoded());
        } catch (CertificateException ce) {
          Trace("Signature verificaton: Failure");
          Trace("Reason: " + ce.getMessage());

          continue;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          Trace("Signature verificaton: Failure");
          Trace("Reason: " + e.getMessage());


          continue;
        } 


        try {
          KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
          PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory
            .generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
          BasicX509Credential publicCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
          publicCredential.setPublicKey(publicKey);
          signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(
              (Credential)publicCredential);
          signatureValidator.validate(signature);
          Trace("Signature verification: Success");
          success = 1;
          break;
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
          Trace("Invalid Signature");
          Trace("Reason: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
      } 

      if (success == 0) {
        Trace("Signature doesn't match with any of the available certificates");
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 


      if (assertion.getConditions() != null) {
        DateTime validFrom = assertion.getConditions().getNotBefore();
        DateTime validTill = assertion.getConditions()
          .getNotOnOrAfter();
        if (validFrom != null && validFrom.isAfterNow()) {
          Trace("Assertion is not yet valid, invalidated by condition notBefore");
          Trace("Authentication failure");
          return false;
        } 
        if (validTill != null && (
          validTill.isBeforeNow() || validTill.isEqualNow())) {
          Trace("Assertion is no longer valid, invalidated by condition notOnOrAfter");
          Trace("Authentication failure");
          return false;
        } 
      } 

      success = 0;
      Subject subject = assertion.getSubject();
      if (subject == null) {
        Trace("Assertion subject cannot be null");
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 


      try {
        String nameID = subject.getNameID().getValue();
        if (!nameID.equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
          Trace("UserName doesn't match with the NameID in Assertion");
          Trace("Authentication failure");
          return false;
        } 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Trace("Problem retrieving NameID from Assertion's subject");
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 


      Iterator<SubjectConfirmation> iterator = subject.getSubjectConfirmations().iterator(); while (iterator.hasNext()) { SubjectConfirmation confirmation = iterator.next();
        if ("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer".equals(confirmation
            .getMethod())) {
          SubjectConfirmationData data = confirmation
            .getSubjectConfirmationData();

          if (data == null) {
            Trace("Bearer SubjectConfirmation invalidated by missing confirmation data");
            continue;
          } 
          if (data.getNotBefore() != null) {
            Trace("Bearer SubjectConfirmation invalidated by not before which is forbidden");
            continue;
          } 
          DateTime expiry = data.getNotOnOrAfter();
          if (expiry == null) {
            Trace("Bearer SubjectConfirmation invalidated by missing notOnOrAfter");
            continue;
          } 
          if (expiry.isBeforeNow() || expiry.isEqualNow()) {
            Trace("Bearer SubjectConfirmation invalidated by notOnOrAfter");
            continue;
          } 
          success = 1;
          break;
        }  }

      if (success == 0) {
        Trace("Not able to validate subject confirmation");
        Trace("Authentication failure");
        return false;
      } 
      Trace("Authentication success");
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Trace("Authentication failure");
      Trace("Reason: " + e.getMessage());

      return false;
    } finally {
      if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
      }
    } 
  }

  public boolean DFCAuthentication(String user, String password, String docbase) {
    IDfSessionManager sessionManager = null;
    IDfSession session = null;
    System.out.println("Calling docbase authentication+++++++");


    try {
      DfClientX dfClientX = new DfClientX();
      IDfClient client = DfClient.getLocalClient();
      sessionManager = client.newSessionManager();
      IDfLoginInfo loginInfo = dfClientX.getLoginInfo();
      loginInfo.setUser(user);
      String pass = "dm_saml=" + password;
       Trace(pass);
      loginInfo.setPassword(pass);
      loginInfo.setDomain(null);
      sessionManager.setIdentity(docbase, loginInfo);
      session = sessionManager.getSession(docbase);
      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

      return false;
    } 
  }
}

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**:

I have a SAML response. I would like to read the encoded SAML response, decode and extract name ID value from the response using Java.

**Answer**:

[OneLogin Java SAML SP](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/onelogin/saml2/authn/SamlResponse.java) at GitHub repository provides the following Java source code to read the encoded SAML response, decode and extract name ID value from the SAML response.

java-saml/core/src/main/java/com/onelogin/saml2/authn/SamlResponse.java

```
/**
     * Gets the NameID provided from the SAML Response Document.
     *
     * @return the Name ID Data (Value, Format, NameQualifier, SPNameQualifier)
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     */
    public Map<String,String> getNameIdData() throws Exception {
        if (this.nameIdData != null) {
            return this.nameIdData;
        }
        Map<String,String> nameIdData = new HashMap<>();

        NodeList encryptedIDNodes = this.queryAssertion("/saml:Subject/saml:EncryptedID");
        NodeList nameIdNodes;
        Element nameIdElem;
        if (encryptedIDNodes.getLength() == 1) {
            NodeList encryptedDataNodes = this.queryAssertion("/saml:Subject/saml:EncryptedID/xenc:EncryptedData");
            if (encryptedDataNodes.getLength() == 1) {
                Element encryptedData = (Element) encryptedDataNodes.item(0);
                PrivateKey key = settings.getSPkey();
                if (key == null) {
                    throw new SettingsException("Key is required in order to decrypt the NameID", SettingsException.PRIVATE_KEY_NOT_FOUND);
                }

                Util.decryptElement(encryptedData, key);
            }
            nameIdNodes = this.queryAssertion("/saml:Subject/saml:EncryptedID/saml:NameID|/saml:Subject/saml:NameID");

            if (nameIdNodes == null || nameIdNodes.getLength() == 0) {
                throw new Exception("Not able to decrypt the EncryptedID and get a NameID");
            }
        } else {
            nameIdNodes = this.queryAssertion("/saml:Subject/saml:NameID");
        }

        if (nameIdNodes != null && nameIdNodes.getLength() == 1) {
            nameIdElem = (Element) nameIdNodes.item(0);

            if (nameIdElem != null) {
                String value = nameIdElem.getTextContent();
                if (settings.isStrict() && value.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new ValidationError("An empty NameID value found", ValidationError.EMPTY_NAMEID);
                }

                nameIdData.put("Value", value);

                if (nameIdElem.hasAttribute("Format")) {
                    nameIdData.put("Format", nameIdElem.getAttribute("Format"));
                }
                if (nameIdElem.hasAttribute("SPNameQualifier")) {
                    String spNameQualifier = nameIdElem.getAttribute("SPNameQualifier");
                    validateSpNameQualifier(spNameQualifier);
                    nameIdData.put("SPNameQualifier", spNameQualifier);
                }
                if (nameIdElem.hasAttribute("NameQualifier")) {
                    nameIdData.put("NameQualifier", nameIdElem.getAttribute("NameQualifier"));
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (settings.getWantNameId()) {
                throw new ValidationError("No name id found in Document.", ValidationError.NO_NAMEID);
            }
        }
        this.nameIdData = nameIdData;
        return nameIdData;
    }
```

**Question 2**:

This is the code I have used but it does not run

**Answer**:

Quote your source code which is the root cause of invalid SAML response due to the authentication failure.

```
    String url = String.valueOf(IDPurl) + "/?SAMLRequest=" + encodedAuthnRequest;
    String samlresponse = request.getParameter("SAMLResponse");
```

You can NOT use the traditional HTTP request/response pair to accomplish the SAML authentication, because SAML relies on a web browser to redirect SAML request from SP to IdP and then redirect SAML response from IdP to SP.

(1) A user accesses SAML SP application.

(2) The user is redirected to SAML IdP with SAML request.

(3) SAML IdP receives the SAML request and then prompts the user to type their username/password credential for identity authentication.

(4) If username/password credential is correct, SAML IdP generates SAML response, and then redirects the user back to SAML SP application while POST SAML response to SAML SP.

**Resolution**:

Separate your source code into two parts to Create two (2) different APIs for your SAML SP (Service Provider) application to send the SAML request to SAML IdP (Identity Provider) and Receive the SAML response from SAML IdP respectively.

For example,

(1) SAML SP API for building SAML request and redirecting SAML request to SAML IdP

```
public String buildAuthenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { 

DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

/*Copy your source code to build SAML authentication request here */

String url = String.valueOf(IDPurl) + "/?SAMLRequest=" + encodedAuthnRequest;

response.sendRedirect(url);

}
```

(2) SAML SP API for receiving SAML response POST by SAML IdP

```
/* See the source code provided by the above Answer for your Question 1 */

or 

/* Your source code for processing SAML response */

public void loadXmlFromBase64(String samlresponse) throws Exception { 

byte[] base64DecodedResponse = Base64.decode(samlresponse);
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64DecodedResponse);


}
```

**Reference**:

[How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository provides the instruction on building a SAML-based Authentication/Authorization Provider using Shibboleth SAML IdP and OpenLDAP and a SAML SP web application.

- Shibboleth SAML IdP is responsible for identity federation.
- OpenLDAP is responsible for identity authentication.

You can use the above GitHub repository to simulate the SAML authentication flow between a SAML IdP and a SAML SP.

In addition, you can build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP to test the SAML authentication flow of your SAML SP.

Comment: could you review my original post and see where I have gone wrong

Comment: I have updated my answer and provide the resolution.